# Optimization of list of numbers with given cost python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

Lets say I have
investments:

```
a)Cost = $10; Projected return = $20
b)Cost = $8; Projected return = $12
c)Cost = $6; Projected return = $19
d)Cost = $4; Projected return = $8
e)Cost = $2; Projected return = $15
```

Is there some sort of algorithm or math system that can optimize the return with a given amount of money to spend? For example get the highest returns while spending $18?  I need this for a much larger and variable set of numbers. So if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I will be using python.

Note, I do not need anyone to solve the thing above.

What do you even call this sort of stuff so I can research it

Comment: Check for Linear Optimization. I remember there are some primitives in SciPy library which might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), specifically an 0-1 knapsack problem.  It is NP-hard.

You also will likely want to research Dynamic Programming.